# Parsing a string that contain Numbers PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing

I have a string that contains 2 informations (1.A Boolean/2.Something(could be number, letter, special chars and could be of any length)).

2 is a user input.

Exemples:

```
(part 1)"true".(part 2)"321654987" => "true321654987"
```

Could also be

```
"false321654987" or "trueweiufv2345fewv"
```

What I need is a way of parsing trought the string to check first if 1 is `true` (if its false do nothing), if it is `true` I need to check if to following part is a positive number higher than 0 (must accepte any number higher than 0 even decimal BUT not bin or hex (well... could be 10 but its would mean ten not two)).

Here is what I tried:

```
//This part is'nt important it work as it should....
if(isset($_POST['validate']) && $_POST['validate'] == "divSystemePositionnement")
{
    $array = json_decode($_POST['array'], true);

    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    {
        switch($key)
        {
            case "txtFSPLongRuban":
                //This is the important stuff HERE.....
                if(preg_match('#^false.*$#', $value))//If false do nothing
                {}
                else if(!preg_match('#^true[1-9][0-9]*$#', $value))//Check if true and if number higher than 0.
                {
                    //Do stuff,
                    //Some more stuff
                    //Just a bit more stuff...
                    //Done! No more stuff to do.
                }
            break;
            //Many more cases...
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I use regEx to parse trought to string. But it does'nt match decimal number.

I know how to do a regEx to parse decimal this is'nt the question.

The question is:

is there already a function in php that match the parsing I need?

If not, do any of you know a more efficient way to do the parsing or should I just add to my regEx the decimal part?

I was thinking something like :

```
test = str_split($value, "true")
if(isNumeric(test[1]) && test[1] > 0)
//problem is that isNumeric accepte hex and a cant have letter in there only straight out int or decimal number higher than 0.
```

Any idea??

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Why do you check if your string begins with false when you do nothing in this case ? The only thing you got to do is to check if it starts with "true"

Comment: Sorry for this I am planning to add a error message on False but I thought it was'nt important for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substr` : [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
if(substr($value, 0, 4) == "true"){
   $number_part = substr($value, 5);
   if(((int) $number == $number) || ((float) $number == $number)){
      //do something...
   }
}
```

Comment: What about the number part?

Comment: Added. I think it was logical after showing the use of substr.

Comment: I'll mix this answer with @MarkB Really like the cast! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
case "txtFSPLongRuban":
    if (preg_match('~^true(?=.*[^0.])([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$~', $value, $match))
    {
        // do what you want with $match[1] that contains the not null number.  
    }
break;
```

The lookahead `(?=.*[^0.])` checks if there is somewhere a character that is not a `0` or a `.`

Answer (score 0):

This oughta do the trick, and handle both types of values:

```
preg_match('/^(true|false)(.*)$/', $value, $matches);

$real_val = $matches[2];

if ($matches[1] == 'true') {
  ... true stuff ...
} else if ($matches[1] == 'false') {
  ... false stuff ...
} else { 
  ... file not found stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
else if(!preg_match('#^true([1-9][0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$#', $value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ctype_digit](https://www.php.net/ctype_digit):

`Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are numerical.`

To check for decimals you can use `filter_var`:

```
if (filter_var('123.45', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) !== false) {
    echo 'Number';
}
```

Comment: Edited answer, added filter_var() that should match float numbers also.